# GLFW3 compile crashes on Centos6: issue with docs?

Tags: centos, doxygen, glfw

I am trying to compile GLFW3 on Centos 6. I downloaded the latest source, I have version of cmake 2.8.12. Here is the sequence of commands I followed:

```
git clone https://github.com/glfw/glfw.git
cd glfw/
cmake .
make
```

It crashes when it gets to making the docs:

```
[100%] Generating HTML documentation
Warning: ignoring unsupported tag `PROJECT_BRIEF          =' at line 41, file Doxyfile
...
/bin/sh: line 1: 14858 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) /usr/bin/doxygen
make[2]: *** [docs/CMakeFiles/docs] Error 139
make[1]: *** [docs/CMakeFiles/docs.dir/all] Error 2
```

So I edited CMakeList.txt and turn documentation OFF:

```
option(GLFW_BUILD_DOCS "Build the GLFW documentation" OFF)
```

I tried everything after that, cmake ., make clean, make, etc. I always get the same problem. It segs fault on creating the HTML documentation, which I don't understand since I am supposed to have turned that off?

The version of doxygen installed is 1.6.1. Yum tells me it's up to date.

Any idea? Thanks a lot.

Edit:

I actually downloaded the latest version of Doxygen (1.8.7) and recompiled it. However, this didn't fix the problem.

Comment: You wrote: "The version of doxygen installed is 1.6.1. Yum tells me it's up to date." Well 1.6.1 is a couple of years old (August 2009) the current version is 1.8.7. Maybe you should download the current version and compile it yourself and try to use this version.

Comment: Yes that's correct, I should have said that. Still, yum wouldn't install a more recent version ;-( using the default repo. However, I downloaded the source code of Doxygen and recompiled it (it's now 1.8.7) and I still had the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a pretty bad solution, as I haven't really got a chance to understand why this happened, but I removed all references to the docs in CMakeList.txt. So anything that is declared in the

```
if (GLFW_BUILD_DOCS)
endif()
```

statement, I removed.

And then it seems to work. I really don't understand why turning documentation off doesn't work, but I'd need to spend more time looking at the way the CMakeList file is built.

This then, is a quick and dirty solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
cmake -DGLFW_BUILD_DOCS=OFF
```

is better than editing the CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Even though the suggestion is better than the solution chosen in answer from user18490, it should have been a comment to the answer. The real question is of course "does the problem still occur in the current version of the glfw package".